# Chamar variável dentrro da função

Tags: python

Como eu chamo uma variável criada fora de uma função dentro de uma função em Python
Por exemplo:

```
variavel=2

def test():
   variavel=variavel+1
   if variavel==3:
      print(variavel)
test()
```

Comment: Em Python as variáveis já declaradas são visíveis dentro do escopo da função para leitura, porém. A melhor coisa que você pode fazer é declarar as variáveis que você deseja usar como argumentos da função, `def test(val2):print(var2)` e indicar a variável já declarada como argumento desta: `test(variavel)`.

Comment: eu não entedi...

Comment: @GiovanniNunes editei o codigo pra você enteder o que eu quero fazer

Comment: @bfavaretto consertei

Comment: Agora o código é diferente do que eu tinha visto. Como disse o @GiovanniNunes, as variáveis de fora seriam visíveis para leitura, mas na hora em que você tenta fazer atribuição precisa existir uma variável local – que você não declarou, por isso o erro. Seria melhor a função receber um argumento e retornar um valor.

Comment: @bfavaretto então. Não tem algum jeito de "chamar" essa variável para dentro da função sem declarar ela dentro da função?

Comment: Tem como, se você declarar a variável como `global` dentro da função. Mas em geral é uma péssima escolha fazer isso. Sugiro uma lida no manual (em EN): https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

Comment: o global só funciona se for declarado dentro da função?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode passar sua variável como parâmetro da função:

```
variavel=2

def test(variavel):
   variavel=variavel+1
   if variavel==3:
      print(variavel)

test(variavel)
```

Percebi que você está iniciando no python, então explicando o que fiz, ao invés de você acessar sua variável dentro da função, você vai passar uma variável para que a função trabalhe com ela. Assim sua função não vai tentar acessar nada que esteja fora do "alcance" dela.
Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: ENTEDIIII!! Caramba cara, grande ajuda,obrigadão!!

Answer (score 1):

Vc poderia fazer:

```
def test(variavel):
   variavel=variavel+1
   if variavel==3:
      print(variavel)

test(2)
```